# JS array to PHP

Tags: php, javascript, arrays

I have an generated **output.js** file from a specific device which contains Array in it:

```
var OUT=new Array (0x80,0x00,0x40,0x0026,0x0011,0x0014,0x0013,0x0018,0x0017,0x03FD,0x0116)
```

How can i get access to this array with PHP, so i can easily print specified Array[x] in any location:

```
print $OUT[4];
```

With simple JS i was able to do it like:

```
document.write(OUT[4]);
```

In case i can also handle that output.js with PHP like a txt file and then splitting and "doing like array thing" but i think there is away to use it right.. ^_^

Any tips or suggestions on that ? :)

Thnx!

Comment: Are you using jQuery on your page?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29

Comment: On my PHP page no, cuz i'm not so good at it yet. But it if it's needed to get what i want, i will.

Comment: Also output.js file can't be modified.

Comment: @45RPM use json, best option you can have

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to fetch the file directly with PHP then you can either write a custom parser (using regular expressions if you can trust the file format to be consistant) or by [interfacing with a JavaScript engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3971232/executing-javascript-within-php).

Otherwise, assuming the JavaScript is running in a web browser…

The simplest way to do this would be to make use of `createElement` and `appendChild` while looping over an array to create a `form` element containing a `hidden` input for each element of the array (with a name such as `foo[]` to satisfy the algorithm PHP uses to populate `$_POST` and friends) and then `submit()` the form.

Alternatively, you could serialise the array to a string (e.g. a comma separated one if you know that there are no commas in the data) and create a query string with it (`var qs = "?foo=" + encodeURIComponent(serialised_array);`) and then pass it using [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest).

Comment: Thnx! `createElement` and `appendChild` Helped a lot! :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use json for doing this

```
var jsonString  = JSON.stringify(OUT);
```

then

```
document.getElementById('IdOfYourFormInputField').value = jsonString;
```

// make element type hidden

now when you submit the form you will get the json string in $_POST field

so you can decode it like

```
$phpArray = json_decode($_POST['NameOfYoutInputEleMent']);
```

That's It!!!

Comment: What if it isn't used in a form?

Comment: @ChristianNikkanen you can post it directly by ajax to your php file without using any form

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to use a library like jQuery rather than roll your own...

```
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js">
....
```

Then at the point you calculate your data, post it to PHP server

```
var OUT = new Array (0x80,0x00,0x40,0x0026,0x0011,0x0014,0x0013,0x0018,0x0017,0x03FD,0x0116);
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://www.example.com/receiver.php'  //change example.com to your server
    ,type: 'POST' //use POST so don't have to worry about URL length
    ,data: {out: OUT} //pass contents of 'OUT' in variable 'out'
    ,dataType: 'json' //use JSON formatting of data
    ,error: function() { 
        alert("Failed to contact server"); 
    }
    ,complete: function() {
        alert("Finished sending data to server.");
    }
});
```

In receiver.php

```
$OUT = json_decode( $_POST['out'] ); // 'out' matches the parameter name in jQuery Ajax call
print_r( $OUT ); //print contents of array $OUT
```